# How to generate an n×2 matrix with randperm

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to write a MATLAB function called `matchUp` using `randperm` that returns an *n*×2 matrix. If the input is an odd number the function should exit and display an explanatory message.

Here is a sample output for n=24:

```
matchUp(24)

ans = 
     6    18
    19    10
    20     4
     5     3
    11    15
    23    12
    13     1
    21    24
     2    22
     9    16
     7    17
    14     8
```

However, when I do `randperm(24)` I get a vector. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking the question in the question title or in the question body, as they're a bit different. With that said, you can do

```
nrows = 2;
ncols = 2;
reshape(randperm(ncols*nrows), [nrows ncols])
```

to get your `2x2` matrix from `randperm`. This works, in that `randperm` will generate an n-element vector, where n is its 1st parameter (here, given by `ncols*nrows`). This column vector is then reshaped into matrix via the `reshape` function, where its 2nd parameter `[nrows ncols]` tells it to turn the vector into a [nrows x ncols] matrix. Also, should I assume this is homework?

Comment: this one seems to work I just changes the 2 on nrows into 12. Thanks!